# cd ~[TAB] doesn't behave as expected

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, completion, tilde

I've encountered an unexpected bebahiour with the completion in bash/zsh in conjunction with the tab key.

When I enter `cd ~` and press [ENTER] on Linux (here Ubuntu 22.04 and latest Raspberry Pi OS) the directory is changed to the home folder.

This is (afaik) called tilde expansion.

When I enter `cd ~` and press [TAB] I'd expect that it simply appends `/` or substitutes `~` with `/home/<username>/`.

Instead a list with suggestions is displayed but none of these suggestions can be found in my home folder.

The first suggestion is `~_apt` and when I choose this, I'm told
`cd: no such file or directory: /nonexistent`

The next suggestion is `~avahi/` and when I choose this I end up in
`/var/run/avahi-daemon`.

There're further suggestions such as `~backup/`, `~messagebus`, `~news`, `~sys/`, `~systemd-coredump/`, etc., most work, some don't.

[image]

So this looks like some pre-configured list of ?shortcuts?.

- Can this be configured?
- Why are there suggestions that doesn't work (`no such file or directory: /nonexistent`)?

Comment: I would expect in zsh to see a list of usernames after the tab (and perhaps the same in bash). If you want to cd into the home directory of user _foo_, you could select by completion a `cd ~foo` from this list. If you don't see such a list, it would make sense to upload a screenshot which shows the effect. Also, it does not make sense to use the tags _bash_ **and** _zsh_ here. You can't use two shells at the same time, and we have no idea which of these shells you are using.

Comment: I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @user1934428: you're right, this are just users. The list relates to the content of /etc/passwd. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. These seem to be the typical user names found in a Linux system.  BTW, you still have not fixed the tags for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~<TAB>` completes a username. `~string` navigates to user `string` home directory.

> So this looks like some pre-configured list of ?shortcuts?.

It is not, these are usernames.

> Can this be configured?

You tagged both bash and zsh, I do not know which one of them are you using.   I know bash. In bash, you can modify the bash-completion functions, depending on the version they are installed. See ex. https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/4f9ad009487452cb5896cd129a7c87ac4196cb21/bash_completion#L272 .

> Why are there suggestions that doesn't work (no such file or directory: /nonexistent)?

There are users with not existent home directories, because they are system or batch users, or there are users with home directories to which your user does not have permissions to navigate to.

> cd ~[TAB] doesn't behave as expected

That is true. In such situations, you could consider adjusting your expectation. `~string` is the standard way to reference some user home directory, there are also less known `~+` `~-` `~5`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html /

Comment: It's the same output in bash and zsh. And in fact this are just users; it relates to the content of /etc/passwd. Thanks a lot!